# Blurring a copy of the current screen then rendering it as a texture in the game pause screen

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx, gsl

I call applyEffect in my game logic when the screen is paused, but the image is not set. In its place i get a black background. I instead expect it to show a blurred texture,  of the form in image below [image: Blurred screen] as expected once I set the gaussian blur shader .

This is sadly the result ;[image: ghost screen appears]

Why is the screen black?

Here is how i call the method

```
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.P) || pause)
                        {

                            state = State.GAME_PAUSED;
    setBackgroundTexture(applyEffect());

    gameScreenGamePauseMenu.sendInMenu();
                            }


    public TextureRegion applyEffect()
        {

            boolean m_fboEnabled = true;
            FrameBuffer m_fbo = null;
            float m_fboScaler = 1;
            TextureRegion m_fboRegion = null;

            int width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
            int height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

            if(m_fboEnabled)      // enable or disable the supersampling
            {
                if(m_fbo == null)
                {
                    // m_fboScaler increase or decrease the antialiasing quality

                    m_fbo = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGB565, (int)(width * m_fboScaler), (int)(height * m_fboScaler), false);
                    m_fboRegion = new TextureRegion(m_fbo.getColorBufferTexture());
                    m_fboRegion.flip(false, true);
                }

                m_fbo.begin();
            }


            if(m_fbo != null)
            {
                m_fbo.end();

                getStage().getBatch().begin();
                getStage().getBatch().draw(m_fboRegion, 0, 0, width, height);
                getStage().getBatch().end();
            }
 return m_fboRegion;

        }
```

Iam using Libgdx to make my game

Comment: I guess you should add the shadersetup since the bug is happening when you add the shader. Moreover i'd change the Format to Format.RGB888 or Format.RGBA8888. I think the gaus meight use the alpha chanel.

Comment: This code doesn't make sense to me. `applyEffect()` returns void but you're using it as a method parameter.

Comment: I take it there's code missing between `fbo.begin()` and `.end()`? That's where you would normally draw stuff to be blurred.